# Using fields from two models in rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-models, fields-for

Post Model

```
has_many :post_contents
accepts_nested_attributes_for :post_contents
```

PostContents Model

```
belongs_to :post
```

Post _form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@post) do |f| %>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
   <div class="form-group">
     <%= f.label :title %>
     <%= f.text_field :title, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Enter post title" %>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
     <%= f.label "Description" %>
     <%= f.text_field :body, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Enter post description" %>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
     <%= fields_for :post_content do |x| %>
       <%= x.label :body %>
       <%= x.cktext_area :body, :ckeditor => {:toolbar => 'Full'} %>
     <% end %>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.submit "Save", class: 'btn btn-success' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
 </div>
</div>
```

I've tried post_content and post_contents

PostContents references post

```
class CreatePostContents < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :post_contents do |t|
      t.references :post, index: true, foreign_key: true
      t.text :body

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

and AddCurrentPostContentIdToPosts

```
class AddCurrentPostContentIdToPosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :posts, :current_post_content_id, :integer
    add_index :posts, :current_post_content_id
  end
end
```

PostContentController

```
 def new
  @post_content = PostContent.new
end

def create
  @post_content = PostContent.new(post_content_params)

  respond_to do |format|
   if @post_content.save
    format.html { redirect_to @post_content, notice: 'Post content was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @post_content }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @post_content.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
   end
 end

 def post_content_params
   params.require(:post_content).permit(:post_id, :body, :posts)
 end
end
```

PostController

```
def new
 @post = Post.new
 authorize @post
end

def create
 @post = Post.new(post_params)
 @post.user = current_user
 respond_to do |format|
  if @post.save
    format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @post }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
   end
 end

 def post_params
   params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body, :current_post_content_id, post_contents_attributes: [:body])
 end
end
```

Sorry for the duplicate fields (:body).

What do you recommend to add the PostContent :body field to the 'posts/_form' when creating a new Post?

Comment: What exactly is your question? are you getting an error or something?

Comment: Not getting an error.  I'm not getting anything.  I'm trying to create a new post (:title and :body) and attach a post_content (:body) to the new post in one simple step.  Currently, I have to create a new post with a title and body then I have to create a new post_content and attach the post_id to a :body field within post_content

Comment: what version of rails are you using? have you checked strong parameters? that might be blocking your param containing the association information. Can you provide the request params when you submit the form?

Comment: I'm using rails 4.  Here are the params for the form I am using.            params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body, :current_post_content_id)

Comment: sorry, I meant the actual params hash you get in your controller after submitting the form. Also, can you try this:

params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body, post_content_attributes: [:body])

see: http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html

Comment: my bad, here's the what I have in create post = Post.new(post_params)
    post.user = current_user.  post_content_attributes: [:body] does not work.

Comment: Justin can you provide an inspection of you params hash, every time you submit a request your server's log should print something like:

Processing by PostsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"title"=>"foobar", "body"=>"lorem..."}

by the way, my bad it should be:
.require(:post).permit(:title, :body, post_contents_attributes: [:body])

post_contents should be plural as it is a has_many association

Comment: "post"=>{"title"=>"Testing params hash", "body"=>"Testing params hash body"}, "post_contents"=>{"body"=>"<p>Testing params hash post_content</p>\r\n"}, "commit"=>"Save"}

Comment: cool, your params look good. Please try

require(:post).permit(:title, :body, post_contents_attributes: [:body])

if that does not work please provide your controller's code

Comment: post_contents_attributes: [:body] doesn't seem to work.  I will include controllers.

Comment: cool, can you also provide the post_params method in your posts controller? Notice that using nested attributes doesn't mean that a request will be sent to your post_contents_controller. Both records will be created in the posts_controller so the 

require(:post).permit(:title, :body, post_contents_attributes: [:body])

should actually be in the post_params method. Is that how you have it? can you provide the full posts controller? or at least that method too?

Comment: Sorry about that, I put the current params under the post.

Comment: I think I got it. See my answer below

Answer (score 0):

As Jose said, it's probably strong parameters blocking your input. You may want to do this:

```
def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:body,:title, post_content_attributes: [:body])
end
```

Comment: I have accepts_nested_attributes_for in my model and fields_for in the _form view.

Comment: Justin, entirely my bad. Gimme a second.

Comment: I just put this suggestion forward and am still coming across the same issue.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @JustinGrant, any chances you could provide `development.log`?

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed your params are not right:

```
"post"=>{"title"=>"Testing params hash", "body"=>"Testing params hash body"}, "post_contents"=>{"body"=>"<p>Testing params hash post_content</p>\r\n"}, "commit"=>"Save"}
```

post_*contents* should be within the posts hash and it is outside. See http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

The reason is that your fields_for is not associated to the original post object, try using this

```
<%= f.nested_fields_for :post_content do |x| %>
```

instead of

```
<%= fields_for :post_content do |x| %>
```

Comment: I get this error "undefined method `nested_fields_for' for #<ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder:0x007fbc639e1570>"

Comment: hmm, how about f.fields_for ?

Answer (score 0):

You should change

```
<%= fields_for :post_content do |x| %>
```

to

```
<%= f.fields_for :post_contents do |x| %> # wrap the fields_for with f
```

The reason why the `post_contents` hash is not inside the `post` hash is because you didn't wrapped `fields_for` with the `form object f` and also notice the change `post_content` to `post_contents` since you have `has_many` relation.

Comment: Hey Pavan! This doesn't seem to solve the problem.  Any other thoughts?

Comment: No error — When adding f.fields_for it removes the :body field for post_contents

Comment: Try changing `cktext_area` to `text_area`

Comment: Same issue — Changed cktext_area to text_area

Comment: I replaced post_contents with post_content — this shows the :body field for post_content. 

Here's the params hash Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"ug9LoHQh9qKKAjORqW3sYr7tsFr3YgDGviVSJns+ONIkf42AdE15REmRCsVKNzH35aHhm4ZPpeatoxHcgnoXdg==", "post"=>{"title"=>"Testing", "body"=>"Testing", "post_content"=>{"body"=>"<p>Testing</p>\r\n"}}, "commit"=>"Save"}
Unpermitted parameter: post_content